# __autoload fails to throw an Exception when it fails to load a class on a static method call

Tags: php, exception, autoload

While attempting to implement some kind of error handling when my __autoload() function fails to load a file I stumbled upon this little 'oddity'.

According to http://nl.php.net/autoload Exceptions thrown from within the __autoload() function can be caught in a catch block since PHP version 5.3+.

> Note:
>   Prior to 5.3.0, exceptions thrown in the __autoload function could not be caught in the catch block and would result in a fatal error. From 5.3.0+ exceptions thrown in the __autoload function can be caught in the catch block, with 1 provision. If throwing a custom exception, then the custom exception class must be available. The __autoload function may be used recursively to autoload the custom exception class.

This works perfectly for the type of error handling I had in mind. The example below works just like I want it to (It throws an exception and it's caught):

```
function __autoload($class) {
    throw new Exception();
}

try {
    new UndefinedClass();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'damnit, it no work!';
}
```

**Output:** damnit, it no work!

If however I try the same concept with a static method call from a undefined class, Exceptions are not thrown, instead I get fed a fatal error.

```
try {
    $a = UndefinedClass::someRandomStaticMethod();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'meh, it no work!';
}
```

**Output:** Fatal error: Class 'UndefinedClass' not found in ************* on line 16

The code above does **not** work. No Exception is thrown. ( same __autoload() function is used ).

http://nl.php.net/autoload mentions nothing about this usecase and this leaves me wondering if I'm doing something terribly wrong here? How can I make my __autoload() function throw exceptions on static method calls of a non-existent class?

If this is simply not possible with the __autoload() function, does spl_autoload() allow this kind of Exception throwing?

---

**@Galled**

Based on the link you provided I changed the __autoload() function to this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    eval('
            class ' . $class . ' {
            };
        ');
    throw new Exception('Im an Exception!');
}
```

Using this version the fatal error in question is no longer fed to my monitor. However, it will now feed me with a different fatal error: the fact that the someRandomStaticMethod() doesn't exist.

I could of course include the declaration of the method within the eval() call. But this is not workable solution, as I would have to redeclare every class my project contains within the __autoload() function just to be able to avoid said fatal error. It's also interesting to know that no Exception is caught, as it seems the fatal error occurs before the Exception is handled, if it is even thrown in the first place.

Comment: I think the first example works because you are instanciated a new object and `__autoload()` triggers with a new instance, meanwhile in the second example you are calling a static method of a class and no object are instanciated so `__autoload()` are not called.

Comment: @Galled If I add 'echo $class;' in my __autoload() function. It will output UndefinedClass 2 times, verifying that __autoload() is called, but the Exception is not thrown in the second case.

Comment: And what is the fatal error you get?

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'UndefinedClass' not found in ************* on line 16` when using the static method call.

Comment: Have you review [this](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#73561) method of `__autoload-exception`??

Comment: @Galled Please see the question edit for my response to that.

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat managed to solve the problem by expanding on the suggestions from Galled. After some more reading, especially here: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#84086 I wrote the following.

```
function __autoload($class) {

    ...

    /* if something and/or everything fails */
    eval('
            class ' . $class . ' {

                public function __construct() {
                    throw new Exception(\'Im an Exception!\');
                }

                public static function __callstatic($method, $arguments) {
                    throw new Exception(\'Im an Exception!\');
                }

            };
        ');
}
```

This variation will now throw `Exceptions` on both use-cases. regardless on the existence of methods within a class.

While the above works, I'm hoping someone can provide a solution that doesn't touch the `eval()` function. As, for some reason, I feel like I just molested PHP.

Comment: This seems really hacky to me, and having an eval in an autoloader will really hurt application performance if your project spans more than a few dozen classes or so.  I'd suggest finding a way to minimize or eliminate the use of static methods instead.  That, or just forgo exception throwing in your autoloader.  I don't think that's recommended anyway.

Comment: Willem, could you please shed some light on whether this actually hurted the performance of the application? I would not think so, because eval() would only occasionally be called... I still do think this is a really bad hack, but there seems to be no alternative...

Comment: @Lex While I haven't actually tested the performance impact of this implementation, I doubt it would have a performance impact at all, the eval + exception throwing should only occur if for some reason the php files of your application are compromised, which should never happen. This implementation is just a safety net for that - extremely rare - occasion to allow your application to 'die' gracefully in the eyes of your users. And no, I haven't found a viable alternative for this as of yet.